# Open a file and replace its content

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a small program to make my life easier. I need the program to open a txt/ini file, delete everything inside it and write what I need.

For example I want a range of 123-353, in increment order:

```
[Pancake123]

info

info

info

[Pancake124]

info

info

info
```

Ahe "info info info" always stays the same in the same order, the only thing I want to change is the range and number of Pancake.

Keep in mind that it's my first program so I don't know anything about it, I just need a program like this to make my life easier.

Comment: an INI file will not make your life easier or sweeter.  You do not have control over the order of section in them unless you delete them and reqrite everything every time.  Consider storing the pancakes in a List(of Pancake) and use XML for the file, maybe serializing the list.

Comment: The program will make my life easier , the INI file is for another program that reads info from it , I want to change this info

Comment: where do you want the data to come from?

Comment: two range input boxes and the program will write everything else, the info info info wont change and the Pancake wont change , only the number after Pancake change

Answer (score 0):

Right click in your code somewhere and choose the Insert Snippets option. Then drill down to file system and eventually write all text. You can edit the model code create to write over your file. No need to open, delete, etc. just write over in stead of append.

Here is a typical result `My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Test.txt", "Text", True)`

The last param should be False to write over the existing file, True appends.

Comment: I'm really new to this , can you give me an example in a code form please? thanks for the answer: )